# QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA to generate a very simple query method, but getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException:
Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
```

This is my method:

```
@Query(" select new AccessLog(acct, auth) from Authentication auth, RadiusAcct acct "
        + " where auth.startDate >= ?1 ")
List<AccessLog> findUnconsolidatedRecords(Date start);
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong? This is bugging me specially because I have written hundreds of queries like that before, and this one looks perfectly normal.

Comment: After a lot of trial-and-error, I verified it is related to the cartesian product in the query (selecting two tables/entities); When I remove one table, the error message ceases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out the problem - I was trying to select entities from two different databases. Hibernate probably "got confused" and gave me a completely non-related error message.